# How to reduce ink flow of Pilot Parallel Pen?

Tags: pens, ink, maintenance

I have a 2.8 Pilot Parallel Pen. It simply flows too much ink when writing. I have the 6mm too and it is just fine. Is there a way to reduce ink amount?

https://pilotpen.com.au/products/parallel-pen/

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts StackExchange! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. Not everyone is familiar with the kind of pen you mention, so a link to a website (of the manufacturer or even a web shop) or a picture of your problematic pen and its writing result would help users who want to answer your question. You can [edit] your post at any time to add more information.

Comment: Is it a pen you dip ie. a problematic nib, or a refillable, or a disposable pen?

Comment: It is a Pilot Parallel Pen which is a fountain pen (so ink comes from a cartridge) with an automatic pen nib (two, nearly parallel metal plates). https://scribblers.co.uk/product-category/dip-pens-and-nibs/automatic-lettering-pens/automatic-pens/

Comment: If it flows way more than the 6mm and it's an improper amount of ink, it may be out of tolerance (a manufacturing defect).  You could ask Pilot or the retailer to replace it.

Comment: Are you using the original ink cartridges and ink?

Answer (score 1):

With most fountain pens, adjusting the rate of inkflow usually comes down to adjusting the fit of the feed (the plastic piece that lies against the nib) to the nib. The bigger the airgap between the two, the faster the inkflow will be, and the smaller the airgap, the slower the inkflow. However, while it's typically very easy to adjust for more inkflow, adjusting for less can be harder and may essentially destroy the pen if you don't know what you're doing, since you may have to heat up the plastic of the feed to reform it.

Most vintage fountain pens have the nib and feed friction fit into the section of the pen (the ring that screws into the barrel), so you could try adjusting the nib up/down, relative to the feed to try and get more or less of the feed in contact with the nib, and see if that does anything. But some modern pens may have the feed/nib secured (glued) to the section in some way, so you might risk breaking it.

Given that there are also two plates in a Pilot Parallel nib, you could also consider adjusting the distance between the plates to affect inkflow. I would suggest wearing gloves, or filling the pen and testing with water, if you want to avoid staining your fingers with ink. :)